# How to execute some code using context before/after all tests with SpringExtension?

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit

I need to execute some initialization / deinitialization code before/after all tests (in all classes) using DI container when `SpringExtension` is used. I tried two solutions:

```
@ExtendWith({BeforeAllAfterAll.class, SpringExtension.class})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ContextConfig.class)
public class ServiceIT{..}

public class BeforeAllAfterAll implements BeforeAllCallback,
     ExtensionContext.Store.CloseableResource {...}
```

However, in `BeforeAllAfterAll` class I can't get reference to application context.

I tried to use events:

```
public class ContextEventHandler {
    
    @EventListener
    public void handleContextStartedEvent(ContextStartedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Context Start Event received.");
    }
    
    @EventListener
    public void handleContextRefreshEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Context Refreshed Event received.");
    }
    
    @EventListener
    public void handleContextStoppedEvent(ContextStoppedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Context Stopped Event received.");
    }
}
```

However, as I found out when `SpringExtension` is used `StartedEvent` and `StoppedEvent` are not fired.

Could anyone say how to do it? I use Spring5 and JUnit5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After studying spring-test source code I did the following solution:

```
public class BeforeAllAfterAll implements BeforeAllCallback, ExtensionContext.Store.CloseableResource {
    
    private static boolean started = false;
    
    private TestEnvironment testEnvironment;
    
    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) {
        if (!started) {
            started = true;
            // Your "before all tests" startup logic goes here
            Namespace springNamespace = Namespace.create(SpringExtension.class);
            Store store = context.getRoot().getStore(springNamespace);
            //we need to pass any test class
            TestContextManager testContextManager = 
                    store.getOrComputeIfAbsent(FooTest.class, TestContextManager::new, TestContextManager.class);
            ApplicationContext applicationContext = testContextManager.getTestContext().getApplicationContext();
            testEnvironment = applicationContext.getBean(TestEnvironment.class);
            testEnvironment.initialize();
            // The following line registers a callback hook when the root test context is shut down
            context.getRoot().getStore(GLOBAL).put("any unique name", this);
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void close() {
        testEnvironment.deinitialize();
    }
}
```

Maybe someone can suggest something better.